# FabricJS Update Bounding Box

Tags: fabricjs

I'm unable to get the bounding box of a canvas to update after panning. I've tried to `requestRenderAll` and to reset the coordinates of each object, but the bounding box stays in the same location.

Is there a different function I should be calling?

Things I've tried:

```
    if (!pausePanning && e.self.x && e.self.y && e.e.type) {
      currentX = e.self.x;
      currentY = e.self.y;
      xChange = currentX - panX;
      yChange = currentY - panY;

      if( (Math.abs(xChange) <= 100) &&
          (Math.abs(yChange) <= 100) ) {
        var delta = new fabric.Point(xChange, yChange);
        canvas.relativePan(delta);
      }

      panX = e.self.x;
      panY = e.self.y;

      // attempting to redraw bounding
      canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(o) {
        o.setCoords();
      });


      // this also doesn't work
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up [filing a ticket](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6113) and heard back; the issue was that you need to specify the updated canvas when you select items after panning or zooming.

An example if your canvas is named as `canvas` variable:

```
var sel = new fabric.ActiveSelection(selection, { canvas: canvas });
canvas.setActiveObject(sel).requestRenderAll();
```

And a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4f2koaL/) showing the zoom/panning with the updated selection.